# How can I reuse and modify a lasso selection in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, selections

I have made a selection using the lasso tool in GIMP (v2.10.14) and I still have it displayed in the selection editor. Can I get my free select points back and edit those? I want to cut out different parts of a figure (whole body, then only the head etc.) and I don't want to retrace the head all over again while this "marching ants" outline is still showing perfectly around the top of the head.

Is it possible to go back to the points of the lasso selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you can't get the original control points back for the selection you already made. However, you can add to, sutbract from, or intersect with your current selection using the controls in the Tool Options.

It might also be possible to do *Select > to Path*, although it will create extra nodes, then you could adjust it as a path, then turn the path into a selection by right clicking it in the Paths panel, and choose Path to Selection.

If you find yourself doing this kind of thing often, and you need a more reliable method, you can learn to use the Paths Tool to create paths which you can always go back to for adjustment.  You can turn any path into a selection by right clicking it in the Paths panel, and choose Path to Selection.  It's also possible to have many paths in a document.

The Paths Tool is more sophisticated than the Lasso Tool, and allows you to create and manipulate Bézier curves as well as having nodes you can adjust.

Answer (score 0):

One solution in your case is to use other selection modes. For instance, cutting out the head is intersecting your clean cutout of the whole body with a rough selection around the head (that only need to be accurate around the neck.

The easiest way to intersect selections is to save them to channels (`Select>Save to channel`, and rename the result). Then you can right-click a channel and `Channel to selection` and right-click more channels and `Intersect with selection`.

See [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Painless-use-of-selection-tools) for some more hints.